# How to make a div occupy 100% within another div in Vue

Tags: html, css

I want to make two div inside other div. But the second(green) div is passing the size of the main(black). I tried to set the height to 100%, but something happens that is going beyond the size of the main box, does anyone have any solutions?

[image: running example]

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}

.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: auto;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="box1">
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a css question not Vue one. Please change tags

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. If you don't know how to do it please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/762001).

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `overflow: hidden;` to the main black box, just like the below snippet. **This will make the overflow clipped.**

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="box1">
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you don't want to get rid of the remaining piece of the second box, you can do it with flexbox also. **This will not trim the green box but instead, it will resize it to make sure the green box will remain in the parent black box.**

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="box1">
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** In the flexbox version, you also won't need to use `margin: auto;` in the child boxes, because in the flexbox column direction `align-items: center;` will take care of child positions with the available attributes it gave to us.

Answer (score 0):

If you set child's height to 100% then the height of the parent will be inherited. If you are looking for an option where the 2nd box (green) fill the remaining space leftover by 1st box(red)

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.box2 {
  flex: 1;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="box1">
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Flex and there is no need to use `overflow: hidden`